# Lock device with device admin but after locking says can only be unlocked using pattern or pin

Tags: locking, fingerprint, device-policy-manager

i am using DevicePolicyManager to lock device but after locking device it says because device is locked by device admin use pattern or pin to unlock cannot unlock using fingerprint.
but i want to lock and unlock using fingerprint also.